# How can I access elements of map in flutter and display them as buttons?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error when trying to follow a course for Flutter.

That what works is that it displays the questions.
I'm struggling with the answers. It should pick the answers from the map I've created.

The error says:
The element type 'Iterable' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

This is my main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/answer.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/question.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;

  // increases the state of questionIndex by 1
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(_questionIndex);
  }

  var questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'Question 1',
      'answers': ['Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3', 'Answer 4']
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Question 2',
      'answers': ['Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3', 'Answer 4']
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Meine erste App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Question(
              questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'].toString(),
            ),
            questions.map((question) {
              return Answer(question);
            })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my answer.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.red,
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Text('Antwort 1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for help

So I followed the course a bit more. Now inside the Flutter app there's the error:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

This is now my code in main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notizapp/answer.dart';
import 'package:notizapp/question.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;

  // increases the state of questionIndex by 1
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(_questionIndex);
  }

  var questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'Question 1',
      'answers': ['Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3', 'Answer 4']
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Question 2',
      'answers': ['Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3', 'Answer 4']
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Meine erste App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Question(
              questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'].toString(),
            ),
            ...(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as List<String>)
                .map((answer) {
              return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
            }).toList()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap:true,
      itemCount:questions.length,
      itemBuilder:(c,i){
        return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed:(){
     //todo handle click event
      },
      child: Text(questions[i]['questionText']),
     );
    }
   )
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this yet. I'm really at the beginning of programming with Flutter and Dart.

Comment: Well ! ListView in Flutter is like RecyclerView in Android and it takes the above parameters and others also. Builder method populates widget(s) by item(s). ElevatedButton is a widget type of Button like CardView in android and has onPressed parameter to handle onClick as Android. Text is to hold text type of data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The cause of the error was simple. I just needed to replace questionText in `...(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as List<String>)` with `...(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>)`. I think flutter expected a list of Strings but just got one String. the question itself. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

This is causing your problem:

```dart
body: Column(
  // The column accepts a list of Widget's.
  children: <Widget>[
    // This is a Widget so it is accepted.
    Question(
      questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'].toString(),
    ),
    // This is not a widget but, the result of a map function.
    questions.map((question) {
      return Answer(question);
    })
  ],
),
```

1. You should use the spread operator to indicate that multiple widgets must be added.

```dart
...questions.map((question) {
  return Answer(question);
}),
```

2. And convert the iterable to a list because the Column widget only accepts a list of widgets.

```dart
...questions.map((question) {
  return Answer(question);
}).toList(),
```